# Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin

Tags: ios, debugging, ionic-framework

I made an ionic app on android, it is working fine ob both desktop and android phone. Now i switched to ios version. It is working fine with safari, but when i start remote debugging or on simulator, the app goes blank. I saw the errors with web inspecting in safari :-

- file:///Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20A63F09-9642-4B4A-A560-ED38FFEF2A95/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59CCC7FD-EEEE-43EC-A833-60CA6322E7E6/Monitz.app/www/templates/login.htmlFailed
  to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load
  file:///Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20A63F09-9642-4B4A-A560-ED38FFEF2A95/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59CCC7FD-EEEE-43EC-A833-60CA6322E7E6/Monitz.app/www/templates/login.html.
  Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

It is not able to find the templates in ionic app. I don't know why. Please help me with this issue.

Thanks